# Validation rule for specific record types, picklist value and specific users

Tags: validation-rule

The criteria I need to meet are:

- Those with a profile name/role containing 'CS' or 'SS' should only be able to change the status to confirmed in a payment record when record type is 1. Example A, 2. Example B or 3. Example C.
- I need to use CONTAINS function as the values 'CS' and 'SS' could change but will always still contain those abbreviations.

I have tried several variations and keep getting syntax errors before I can even save. Ex of what I have tried:

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "confirmed") ,  
    CONTAINS($Profile.Name , "SS"))  ||  
    CONTAINS($Profile.Name , "CS") 
    OR(
        RecordType.DeveloperName  <> "Example A",   
        RecordType.DeveloperName  <> "Example B",   
        RecordType.DeveloperName  <> "Example C"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

- `CONTAINS()` is case-sensitive, you may or may not want to call `UPPER()` and pass the profile name into it to ensure that case sensitivity is not an issue
- You shouldn't mix the `OR()` and `AND()` style with the `||` and `&&` style conditions. It is valid syntax, but harder to read and more prone to errors (i.e. the comparisons probably aren't going to be made in the order you expect them to unless you know what you're doing). I personally advocate for using `OR()` and `AND()`
- The developer name of a recordtype will never contain spaces. I understand that you're giving us generic examples here, but it's still something to keep in mind
- Indenting your formula every time (or almost every time) that you use an open parenthesis (`(`) makes it easier to see mistakes

The syntax of your example looks broadly correct. Outside of your mixing of `OR()` with `||` (another way to say "x or y"), the main issue that I see is that you're using `OR()` to test for multiple record types. You also have an extra close parenthesis that's messing things up.

A record can only have one record type, so `OR(recordType.Name <> "rectype 1", recordType.Name <> "rectype 2")` will *always return true* because it will always be not equal to at least one of those record types. Similarly, `AND(recordType.Name = "rectype 1", recordType.Name = "rectype 2")` would be problematic.

If you're checking against recordtypes

- use equals for `OR()`
- use not equals for `AND()`

In your case, you want your validation rule to complain (i.e. the result of the formula should be `true`) if the record type is not equal to *all* of your 3 allowed options. You need to be using `AND()` here instead of `OR()`

This means your validation rule formula should look like

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "confirmed"),
    OR(
        /* In your example, this line had an extra close paren */
        CONTAINS($Profile.Name , "SS")
        CONTAINS($Profile.Name , "CS") 
    )
    /* You don't need this nested AND(), but it can help people down the line */
    /*   to read and digest what the validation rule is doing */
    AND(
        RecordType.DeveloperName  <> "Example A",   
        RecordType.DeveloperName  <> "Example B",   
        RecordType.DeveloperName  <> "Example C"
    )
)
```

The other thing that you're missing is a check to see if the status is changing. You need to both check to see if a field is changing (using `ISCHANGED()`) and what the current value is.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and clarification, I added in ISCHANGED(Status__c)  and your rule works. Thank you!